# Matrix is not the same size

Tags: matrices

I am trying to write this matrix

[image]

But this matrix is awful aesthetically. The middle matrix is tall, the other two are short. I want to make all 3 matrixes the same height.

This is my Latex code:

```
\tt \color{Black}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 13 & -10\\
0 & 7 & \phantom{-} 17 
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
I_{1}\\
I_{2}\\
I_{3}
\end{bmatrix}

=

\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}0\\
\phantom{-}4\\
-3
\end{bmatrix}
```

But this is my problem. I am using macOS Pages that have limited Latex support. [This is what apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) has to say about it.

Unfortunately [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/912925/316469) solution is not working.

Is there a way to make everything the same height?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the supported commands and it says that `\color` is supported. This allows one to cheat by putting a white, i.e. invisible, dot on top of the symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}1} & -1 & -1\phantom{0}\\
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0} & 13 & -10\\
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0} & \phantom{-}7 & \phantom{-} 17 
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{1}\\
I_{2}\\
I_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
%
=
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0}\\
\phantom{-}\color{white}\dot{\color{black}4}\\
-\color{white}\dot{\color{black}3}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

I Just checked myself, if you remove the `%`, i.e. insert

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}1} & -1 & -1\phantom{0}\\
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0} & 13 & -10\\
\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0} & \phantom{-}7 & \phantom{-} 17 
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
I_{1}\\
I_{2}\\
I_{3}
\end{bmatrix}

=

\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}\color{white}\dot{\color{black}0}\\
\phantom{-}\color{white}\dot{\color{black}4}\\
-\color{white}\dot{\color{black}3}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

you'll get

[image]

(For other Mac users: in a document inside the text, click on the `insert` symbol, which looks a bit like a reverse double-stroke P, and click `insert equation`, you'll be able to verify that it works. Whether or not this is an appropriate question for this site, I cannot judge.)

**NOTE**: I removed the `\vphantom` parts I had originally as this seems not to be supported by pages.

Comment: In a case like this, rather than a `\vphantom`, I’d use a `\mathstrut` (which *is* itself a `\vphantom`, namely `\vphantom (`) everywhere.

Comment: Also beware that, in the last matrix, `-3` should now be `{-3}` (the `\vphantom` inserts an empty box, which is a `\mathord`).  The same remark applies to @mas’ answer too.

Comment: `\vphantom` is not working for me. Like I said, Pages has a very limited set of Latex. I have tried `\phantom` and it almost works. The matrices got equal sizes but the alignment is gone.

Comment: There is a minor typo on your code... on the part you type `\phantom{-1}7`... I think the correct is `\phantom{-}7`. Adding the `1` shifts the `7` slightly to the right on my Pages. Anyway, your code is fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Let me ask you something. I have another question about latex on mac, that is how to create a box around a formula. I have searched the whole web and nothing works. Do you by any chance know? If you say yes I will open another question, to let you earn a few points... 

Comment: I don't know where these options you say are... text wrap???

Comment: @SpaceDog Again a message [that has been swallowed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/do-you-also-fail-to-get-some-messages). In the right area there is a tab called "Arrange", that's where these options are. Notice that I (almost) never used pages and I have absolutely no idea how things work there. And given our discussion here, I do not have any real motivation to ever use pages. And I think there must be other sites where you could ask Mac related things and get a competent answer, I am the least competent source. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to marmot's answer, you can use mathtools to right justify the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                   
\usepackage{mathtools}                                                                    
\begin{document}                                                                          
\[                                                                                        
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]                                                                       
\vphantom{I_{1}}1 & -1 & -1\\                                                             
\vphantom{I_{1}}0 & 13 & -10\\                                                            
\vphantom{I_{1}}0 & 7 & 17                                                                
\end{bmatrix*}                                                                            
%                                                                                         
\begin{bmatrix}                                                                           
I_{1}\\                                                                                   
I_{2}\\                                                                                   
I_{3}                                                                                     
\end{bmatrix}                                                                             
%                                                                                         
=                                                                                         
%                                                                                         
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]                                                                       
\vphantom{I_{1}} 0\\                                                                      
\vphantom{I_{1}} 4\\                                                                      
\vphantom{I_{1}}-3                                                                        
\end{bmatrix*}                                                                            
\]                                                                                        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vphantom` is not working for me. Like I said, Pages has a very limited set of Latex. I have tried `\phantom` and it almost works. The matrices got equal sizes but the alignment is gone. BTW that is the meaning of having `bmatrix` and `bmatrix*`?